# C# Dynamic Button Naming

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button, dynamic

So I am having trouble solving a problem naming buttons on a calender that I am creating. I have created 35 buttons named `sun1-sun5, mon1-mon5, etc... to sat1-sat5`.

I would like to be able to have the correct number corresponding to the day in each of my buttons. For instance`in November the 1st was on a Friday so button fri1 = 1 and the last day in November is Saturday the 30th so sat5 = 30`. First I will link my c# method I am attempting to set the buttons with.

```
     private void setButtons(string firstDay, int totalDays)
    {
        string[] buttonDay = {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"};
        int startDay = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int week = 1;
        if (firstDay == dayOfWeek[0]) { sun1.Content = 1; startDay = 0; }
        if (firstDay == dayOfWeek[1]) { mon1.Content = 1; startDay = 1; }
        if (firstDay == dayOfWeek[2]) { tue1.Content = 1; startDay = 2; }
        if (firstDay == dayOfWeek[3]) { wed1.Content = 1; startDay = 3; }
        if (firstDay == dayOfWeek[4]) { thu1.Content = 1; startDay = 4; }
        if (firstDay == dayOfWeek[5]) { fri1.Content = 1; startDay = 5; }
        if (firstDay == dayOfWeek[6]) { mon1.Content = 1; startDay = 6; }

        for (i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
        {
            buttonDay[startDay]+(string)week.Content = i+1; //this line of code has
                                                            //an error since it does
                                                            //not recognize .Content
                                                            //because the string is
                                                            //not seen as a button name
        }

    }
```

Next I will link the xaml code for the buttons.

```
 <Button Content="" Margin="-11,132,391,0" 
                            Name="sun1" 
                            Background="Gray"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                            BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,132,0,0" Name="mon1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,132,0,0" Name="tue1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,132,0,0" Name="wed1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,132,0,454" Name="thu1" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,132,0,0" Name="fri1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,132,-8,0" Name="sat1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,200,0,0" Name="sun2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,200,0,0" Name="mon2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,200,0,0" Name="tue2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,200,0,0" Name="wed2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,200,0,0" Name="thu2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,200,0,0" Name="fri2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,200,-7,0" Name="sat2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" Margin="-12,270,392,0" Name="sun3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,270,0,0" Name="mon3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,270,0,0" Name="tue3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,270,0,0" Name="wed3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,270,0,0" Name="thu3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,270,0,0" Name="fri53" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,270,-7,0" Name="sat3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-11,336,0,0" Name="sun4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,336,0,0" Name="mon4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,336,0,250" Name="tue4" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,336,0,0" Name="wed4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,336,0,0" Name="thu4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,336,0,0" Name="fri4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,336,-8,0" Name="sat4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,404,0,0" Name="sun5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,404,0,0" Name="mon5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,404,0,0" Name="tue5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,404,0,0" Name="wed5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" Margin="255,404,125,0" Name="thu5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,404,0,0" Name="fri5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Content="" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,404,-7,0" Name="sat5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
```

So I guess the part that I am stuck on is naming a button dynamically that is already created. Thank you for your help and time, it's much appreciated!

Comment: You need to use an itemscontrol for this. Let XAML figure out the buttons, just have the data. You aren't even sure if you need 30, you may need 28 to 31. Do not declare them statically in XAML. Check out the MVVM pattern, Databinging and ItemsControls.

Comment: Why don't you use DatePicker instead of creating 35 buttons?